# google maps show your own location and also show multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geolocation

I've checked all over the internet and I have tried some solutions but can't seem to find out how to combine your own location and at the same time show some markers on the map.

I got this code to show multiple markers and it works great but how do I call my own location with google maps as well? 
I know there is documentation on how to add your own location but not to combine these two options.

Edit regarding duplicates:

There is no question like this on stackoverflow and is therefore no duplicate as there is no question **regarding combining multiple markers and show your own location marker.**

Here's the code I got right now:

```
     <script>

        function initialize() {
            var map;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };




            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            map.setTilt(45);


            var markers = [
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
    ['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567]
            ];




            var infoWindowContent = [
                ['<div class="info_content">' +
                '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
                '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
                ['<div class="info_content">' +
                '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
                '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
                '</div>']
            ];




            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

           // Here we get our own location

    var showPosition = function (position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLatLng,
        title: 'Your Location',
        map: map
    });
}

    // Show all the markers and show my own location. Show my own location don't work.

    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2], showPosition); 
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });


                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));


                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }


            var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                this.setZoom(11);
                google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
            });

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple markers Google Map API v3 from array of addresses and avoid OVER\_QUERY\_LIMIT while geocoding on pageLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640055/multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-array-of-addresses-and-avoid-over-query)

Comment: It's not a duplicate... That one doesn't show it's own location as well.

Comment: Ah, can't you just push your own location in the array as an array?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how... something like this?
['some locations, city', 52.35475,19.532567],
[(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)]

Comment: `var myLocation = ['some locations, city', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]; markers.push(myLocation);`

Comment: Thanks but it's causing the map to be gray.

I got a codepen here:http://codepen.io/Adamnorbacker/pen/xERzLR

Comment: It's partly because you're using an unsecure origin. I'm answering your question below, and that code should work on localhost or https.

Comment: It looks like variable position is undefined in your code. There is an error message in console. I think you should use [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation). Also have a look at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

Comment: Thank you xomena, Can't get it to work yet tho.

Comment: Why downvote? 
The question is stated clearly and it's also clearly stated that it ain't a duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google maps multiple markers with geolocation button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982038/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-geolocation-button)

Comment: Oh haven't seen this one, however, It doesn't show a marker of where you are. Only zooms in to location.

Comment: See the javascript console: getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

Comment: Actually, I managed to solve it geocodezip.
It apparently worked on your code.
Here's the code/ fiddle you provided with some edits:
https://jsfiddle.net/k4kqg1gw/10/
I would uprate it if I had enough repetition but It seems I can't get to the rep limit by some odd reasons.

Also, both codepen and jsfiddle has a https domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it by using geocodezips answer on: [Google maps multiple markers with geolocation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982038/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-geolocation-button)

Didn't have marker but managed to add it myself by some code Roberrrt provided before.
Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4kqg1gw/27/

```
['Helooo',40, 30 ,0] , ['Helooo',41.04564,28.97862 ,1], ['Your location',position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude] , ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following JavaScript code below your declaration of `var markers`

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(callback) {
            showPosition(callback)
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    markers.push(['test', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
}

getLocation();
```

We're grabbing the user location, and pushing it in the initial array of array's that hold the data for the markers, please note that this doesn't work on http, because Google discourages the usage of the getCurrentPosition() by disabling it on unsecure origins. Localhost should work, as it is considered 'safe-ish'

Comment: Hmm really nice of you, but can you verify that it works?

my ampps localhost does not show my own location/marker but it asks for it. 

here's the codepen, the same code I have in my localhost: https://codepen.io/Adamnorbacker/pen/xERzLR

Comment: You'll have to allow your browser to get your location ofc.

Comment: It asks for my location and i allow it too. hmm, tried on safari and firefox.
I appreciate your help :)